# Generics - The method in the type is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

I am using an external library which contains a method :

```
public <V> List<V> getObjectsForHashCriteria(@NonNull final Class<V> clazz,     @NonNull final V hashObject) {
final DynamoDBQueryExpression<V> queryExpression = new     DynamoDBQueryExpression<V>().withHashKeyValues(hashObject);
return dynamoDBMapper.query(clazz, queryExpression,
            dynamoDBMapperConfig);
}
```

I want to invoke the above method. To get the class object, I am passing it in the constructor. Something like this :

```
MyClass(final @NonNull Class<T> clazz){
this.clazz = clazz}
```

Inorder to invoke the getObjectsForHashCriteria(), I am currently doing it as shown below but it shows compilation error :

```
public <T> List<T> fetchObjectsForHashCriteria(@NonNull final T hashObject){
instance.getObjectsForHashCriteria(clazz, hashObject);
}
```

But it shows a compilation error :

> The method getObjectsForHashCriteria(Class,V) is not applicable for
>   the arguments (Class,T).

So basically I am trying to pass generic type parameters as generic type arguments. Please let me know what is the issue with this ? If this is not possible, is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: You have two different `T` generics, you're overshadowing the class-level (if it is class-level) generic with your new `<T>`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. Could you please clarify a bit more ?

Comment: when you declare `<T> List<T>` on your method, you are declaring a type witness of type `T`. This `T` (on the `#fetchObjectsForHashCriteria` method) is fundamentally different from the `Class<T>` in your constructor.

Comment: Show the declaration of `instance`

Comment: @Rogue So what would be the right way of doing this ? I want to use the same generic type that I am using in the class as the argument as well as return type for the method.

Comment: What is the purpose of `MyClass`? You could directly call the `getObjectsForHashCriteria` method from anywhere right?

Comment: Looks like someone already answered below the correct way, you want the class-level generic and no new witness declared on the method

Comment: `public static<T> boolean isListNullOrEmpty(List<T> value) {
  return (value == null) || value.size() == 0;
 }` ... Try using that on a List of a custom type implementing Comparable you get the exact same method. I think T may only apply to primitives perhaps. My IDE is saying I need to implement.  `isListNullOrEmpty(List<custom type>)` .. Sort of defeats the purpose of generics! -1 for Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show your complete class `MyClass`, but I presume it looks like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    // ...

    MyClass(final @NonNull Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public <T> List<T> fetchObjectsForHashCriteria(@NonNull final T hashObject) {
        instance.getObjectsForHashCriteria(clazz, hashObject);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this: The method `fetchObjectsForHashCriteria` has its own type parameter `T` which is separate from the type parameter `T` of class `MyClass`, even though they both happen to be named `T`.

Remove the type parameter `T` on the method; let it use the `T` from the class instead:

```
// Note: no <T> type parameter
public List<T> fetchObjectsForHashCriteria(@NonNull final T hashObject) {
    instance.getObjectsForHashCriteria(clazz, hashObject);
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! So I understood now that using <T> was making it another generic type. I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Thanks!